# How do I write a script that iterates over input values?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a script that iterates over an unspecified number of input values and performs the same operation on each.  Something like the file `~/bin/trash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in "$@"
do 
    mv f ~/trashcan
done
```

which I intend to use like so

```
$touch 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt  # create demo files
$trash *.txt
```

As written, when running this on Git Bash (on Windows) I get the following error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `2.txt'
```

Comment: Can you post the original script or at least a correct example? https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: The error message you have written is unlikely to have come from the script you have posted. On that basis there's no point trying to answer this question as written - at least until you [edit] it.

Comment: @tomasz, that is the original script, copied and pasted from the file I was using to test this.

Comment: @roaima, `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '2.txt'` is the original error message.  When I made @GillesQuenot's recommended change, replacing `mv f ~/trashcan` with `mv "$f" ~/trashcan`, the error was resolved and the script functioned as intended.  I updated the question to clarify that I experienced this when using Git Bash from [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f; do 
    mv "$f" ~/trashcan
done
```

- the `$` 'sigil is mandatory to *call* a declared variable (`$f`)
- no need `for f in "$@"` here

Comment: Umm... actually no need for `for` here.  `mv "$@" "$HOME/trashcan"`.

Comment: I presume OP give just a tiny example, and have more processing, but true

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you have forgotten the `$` in front of `f` in the loop body.  This should also be properly quoted as `"$f"` to support filenames with spaces etc.  I'm not sure this is the cause of your error message though (and I see nothing in the code that would cause that error to appear). The error I would expect is `No such file or directory` when trying to move a nonexisting `f`.

---

For a small utility like this, you could just turn it into a shell function in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
trash () {
    local trashcan="$HOME/trashcan"
    mkdir -p "$trashcan"

    mv -f -v "$@" "$trashcan"
}
```

This function makes sure that the trash folder actually exists before moving things into it.  It will also perform the move verbosely, displaying the names of the things that are moved.

There is no need to iterate here as `"$@"` will correctly expand to the names given to the function on the command line.

The only reason I can see for wanting to actually iterate over the names is if you want to make sure that the target of the `mv` does not exist before performing the move (so that things in the trash won't get overwritten by new items). With `mv` from GNU coreutils, you can do that automatically with something like

```
mv -f -v --backup=numbered "$@" "$trashcan"
```

With non-GNU `mv` you may want that loop (this is replacing the `mv` in the shell function above):

```
local trash_ext="$RANDOM"

for name; do
    while [ -e "$trashcan/${name##*/}.$trash_ext" ]; do
        trash_ext="$RANDOM"
    done

    mv -f -v "$name" "$trashcan/${name##*/}.$trash_ext"
done
```

This is just a quick-and-dirty way of creating a unique name by adding random number after the filename.  The `${name##*/}` thing will expand to the basename (the filename part of the pathname) of `$name` and could be replaced by `$( basename "$name" )`.